# What is the meaning behind Tommy Wiseau's SHAME ON YOU video?

Tags: the-room, tommy-wiseau

I went to a theater showing of *The Room* last night, and before the movie started I got hit with this very aggressive message:

It's a bunch of explosions with apparently accusations against Tommy Wiseau or The Room coupled with the messages SHAME ON YOU and YOU KNOW WHO YOU ARE.

It's on Tommy's YouTube account so I assume it's a message from him to somebody. Problem is I have no clue what it's referring to or why it's important enough to headline his movie. From what I can tell, people have been mostly receptive to The Room and I'm not aware of anybody who's purposely claiming that the movie wasn't done with a crew or wasn't done with professional equipment. What's the meaning behind this video?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That video is the response to supposedly falsified information given in home video of the film. It's all described in video itself.

But he never stopped at one video and made sequel of it. Second one is called ***Shame On You, Part 2: The Shaming Continues*** which was a response to Sandy Schklair's claim of being a director.

Then he made third video title ***Shame On You, Part 3: The Reckoning** which is a response to the film [*Room Full of Spoons (2016)*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4177972/?ref_=nm_knf_t1) which is a documentary about Tommy Wiseau's 2003 film *The Room*.

From [hollywoodreporter.com](https://www.hollywoodreporter.com/news/room-doc-maker-falling-tommy-wiseau-interesting-person-michael-jackson-1018138):

> Despite initially having Wiseau’s blessing and cooperation to make a documentary about The Room, which still sells out cinemas internationally, things soon went awry, with the subject pulling out over creative differences. But Harper plowed on regardless, interviewing most of the cast and crew about undoubtedly the most notorious title on their resumes, deconstructing several of the film’s more widely-ridiculed scenes and even investigating the director’s secrecy-shrouded heritage (he’s actually Polish, and Wiseau isn't his original name).
>
> But as Harper nears completion on the documentary, given the title Room Full of Spoons (pictures of spoons crop up an ordinate number of times in the film, with fans taking plastic spoons to throw at special screenings), Wiseau’s opposition to it stepped up several notches.
>
> Harper claims he was issued with a growing list of impossible and crazy demands (“make the film 60 percent more positive”) from his former collaborator, who then went after any festival or theater who agreed to have it in their schedule, forcing them to remove it. He even went so far as to post a trio of amateurish, angry and explosion-filled videos on YouTube entitled ‘Shame on You’ aimed at discrediting the doc, the third ending with a Room Full of Spoons poster being blown up (the first, naturally, ended with a minute long advert for Tommy Wiseau underwear).